# Bluetooth device has to be re-added every time I reboot

Tags: bluetooth, thinkpad, 18.04

I'm using a Thinkpad T460S and on 16.04, the Bluetooth worked with my Bose headphones just fine. Now that I've upgraded to 18.04, it paired and worked successfully the first time, but every time I reboot I have to remove the device and re-add it for it to connect. I can manually turn the bluetooth connection switch on for my headphones and it will connect, but then it immediately disconnects, reconnects, disconnects, and stays disconnected. Any help on how to go about debugging this?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be mostly fixed in 18.04, kernel version 4.15.0-32. It may have been fixed before that but definitely here. If my machine has been suspended and I bring it back up and my headphones are already on, I have to manually turn the Bluetooth connection on (Bluetooth Settings > Select Device > Toggle "Connection" switch to "On"), but otherwise it works just as expected.